Isaac Newton and Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz were truly hostile towards each other (including subjects beyond differential and integral calculus)?
Are there reliable sources that attest to the rivalry and possible hostility between Newton and Leibniz? Did they exchange hostile messages? On subjects other than differential and integral calculus?

They never met, and never exchanged messages directly. Initially they corresponded through the secretary of the Royal Society (Oldenburg), and the correspondence was friendly. The rivalry started much later, and they did not exchange any direct messages. All this was done through the proxies.

What have you read so far? Do you have any hints of something hostile might have taken place?

A.R. Hall, Philosophers at War. The Quarrel between Newton and Leibniz (1980)

@
Mauricio, perhaps this is an urban legend but I gear sibce ny ubdergratuate times. yet, please3, see https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-51744-1_33

There is another book on the topic, The Calculus Wars, by J.S. Bardi which I haven't read. But I found this book review by an expert (B.E. Blank) in the Notices of the AMS (2009) very useful and informative.

Sonar, T. (2018). The History of the Priority Di∫ pute Between Newton and Leibniz: Mathematics in History and Culture. Birkhäuser.

@AlexandreEremenko, your assumption is incorrect.  Some anonymous tracks were published that were extremely hostile to Leibniz.  Later it was proved that they were penned by Newton.  Thus it is not correct to assume that "all this was done through the proxies".

This isn't direct communication, but apparently Newton and Leibniz disagreed sharply in matters of theology, and Leibniz expressed his disagreements with some hostility. From the Wikipedia article on Newton, in the Theology section:

He [Newton] believed in a rationally immanent world, but he rejected the hylozoism implicit in Leibniz and Baruch Spinoza. The ordered and dynamically informed Universe could be understood, and must be understood, by an active reason. In his correspondence, Newton claimed that in writing the Principia "I had an eye upon such Principles as might work with considering men for the belief of a Deity".[158] He saw evidence of design in the system of the world: "Such a wonderful uniformity in the planetary system must be allowed the effect of choice". But Newton insisted that divine intervention would eventually be required to reform the system, due to the slow growth of instabilities.[159] For this, Leibniz lampooned him: "God Almighty wants to wind up his watch from time to time: otherwise it would cease to move. He had not, it seems, sufficient foresight to make it a perpetual motion."[160]

The citation [160]:
H.G. Alexander (ed) The Leibniz-Clarke correspondence, Manchester University Press, 1998, p. 11.

What's hylozoism?
